# An Efficient Way to Compute Solutions of System of Inequalities in R

Tags: r

I am stuck on a problem that says given for the range [750,1800] (where each element has a spacing of 5 units: [750,755,760,...,1795,1800]), to select 4 elements from this range who are **all *at least*** 150 units apart from each other. I have to implement this in R. Ideally, I would like to hope to find more than 1 solution, but finding all possible solutions is not necessary.

I was wondering if anyone had any solutions that would be quick in solving this problem in R. (Eventually, I would like to take arbitrary vectors/ranges/lengths, etc... but am just starting with this problem as an example).